# maxima: how to make a quotient of two polynomials a polynomial

Tags: division, maxima, polynomials

I'm trying to divide two polynomials in maxima:

```
f(x,y) = x*y;    
g(x,y) = x;
```

How do i save the result of their division as a new polynomial h(x,y)? i have tried this:

```
h(x,y) := quotient(f(x,y),g(x,y));
```

It didn't work, because asking for h(0,0) gives me the "division by zero" error.

I need the solution only for cases where f is divisible by g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here. (1) Remember ":" is the assignment operator; "=" means an equation or equality, while ":=" is a function definition. For `f` and `g`, it is possible to get a workable solution using either ":" or ":="; I'll show both below.

(2) The right-hand side of a function definition in ":=" isn't evaluated (or even simplified), so when you write `h(x, y) := quotient(...)`, the quotient is not evaluated, and the definition of `h` contains the call to `quotient`. When you call `h(0, 0)`, you'll have `quotient` evaluated with x = 0 and y = 0, which yields a number instead of a symbolic expression.

I guess that what you want is to define a function `h` such that `h(x, y)` is the quotient of `f` and `g` evaluated at `x` and `y`. If so, here's a solution using ":" for `f` and `g`.

```
f : x*y;
g : x;
define (h(x, y), quotient(f, g));
```

`define` evaluates the function body (the second argument), so the quotient is carried out before the function is defined.

Maxima mostly prefers expressions, but one can also define `f` and `g` as functions here.

```
f(x, y) := x*y;
g(x, y) := x;
define (h(x, y), quotient(f(x, y), g(x, y)));
```

I know this stuff is a little confusing since there is more than one way to do it.